# ¿Como recuperar mi cuenta mysql?

Tags: mysql

hace poco empece con mysql en mi computadora para ponerla en un servidor nodejs. Yo no se nada de estas dos cosas, recién estoy empezando pero no se si toque algo o que hice que de un día para el otro mi contraseña de toda la vida me dice que no es y ahora no se que hacer. ¿Se puede borrar todo mysql y crear una "cuenta" nueva por así decirle y ponerle otra contraseña o que se podría hacer?

Muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿cuàl es tu sistema operativo?

Comment: windows 10, ahora cuando quiero poner cualquier comando mysql me tira un error que es: ERROR 2003 (HY 000): Cant connect to mysql server on localhost (10061)

Comment: Eso no es problema de contraseña. Tu script o lo que estés intentando conectar no encuentra el servidor. O bien cambió de dirección, o de puerto, o el servicio está detenido. ¿Has verificado si el servicio de mysql está corriendo?

Comment: yo quiero prender el servidor de mysql desde cmd algo tan facil como eso... si fui a servicios pero no me aparece nada de mysql

Comment: Revisa en el administrador de tareas a ver si consigues mysqld activo o corriendo. A mi también me parece que tu mysql está detenido no que tengas problemas de credenciales... Prueba reiniciando el PC y si no ve a la carpeta de instalación de MySQL y en la carpeta "bin" ejecuta mysqld-nt.exe